# Angular watch changes in DOM element

Tags: javascript, angular, real-time

I have some real-time feed coming to my page with Nodejs and Socket.io to my page like this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
      const socket = io.connect('http://###.###.###.###:4000');
      socket.on('update', update => {
        //console.log(update);
  if(update.symbol === "EURUSD") {
      $bid = parseFloat(update.bid);
   $ask = parseFloat(update.ask);
   $spread = ($ask - $bid)*10000;
   $('.eurusd').html('<div class="symbol">'+update.symbol+'</div><div class="bid">'+$bid.toFixed(5)+'</div><div class="ask">'+$ask.toFixed(5)+'</div><div class="pips">'+$spread.toFixed(2)+'</div>')
  }
  if(update.symbol === "GBPUSD") {
      $bid = parseFloat(update.bid);
   $ask = parseFloat(update.ask);
   $spread = ($ask - $bid)*10000;
   $('.gbpusd').html('<div class="symbol">'+update.symbol+'</div><div class="bid">'+$bid.toFixed(5)+'</div><div class="ask">'+$ask.toFixed(5)+'</div><div class="pips">'+$spread.toFixed(2)+'</div>')
  }
  if(update.symbol === "USDJPY") {
      $bid = parseFloat(update.bid);
   $ask = parseFloat(update.ask);
   $spread = ($ask - $bid)*100;
   $('.usdjpy').html('<div class="symbol">'+update.symbol+'</div><div class="bid">'+$bid.toFixed(3)+'</div><div class="ask">'+$ask.toFixed(3)+'</div><div class="pips">'+$spread.toFixed(2)+'</div>')
  }  
        if(update.symbol === "AUDUSD") {
      $bid = parseFloat(update.bid);
   $ask = parseFloat(update.ask);
   $spread = ($ask - $bid)*10000;
   $('.audusd').html('<div class="symbol">'+update.symbol+'</div><div class="bid">'+$bid.toFixed(5)+'</div><div class="ask">'+$ask.toFixed(5)+'</div><div class="pips">'+$spread.toFixed(2)+'</div>')
  }
  if(update.symbol === "USDCAD") {
      $bid = parseFloat(update.bid);
   $ask = parseFloat(update.ask);
   $spread = ($ask - $bid)*10000;
   $('.usdcad').html('<div class="symbol">'+update.symbol+'</div><div class="bid">'+$bid.toFixed(5)+'</div><div class="ask">'+$ask.toFixed(5)+'</div><div class="pips">'+$spread.toFixed(2)+'</div>')
  }
  if(update.symbol === "USDCAD") {
      $bid = parseFloat(update.bid);
   $ask = parseFloat(update.ask);
   $spread = ($ask - $bid)*10000;
   $('.usdcad').html('<div class="symbol">'+update.symbol+'</div><div class="bid">'+$bid.toFixed(5)+'</div><div class="ask">'+$ask.toFixed(5)+'</div><div class="pips">'+$spread.toFixed(2)+'</div>')
  }
  else {
   
  }
      })
    }
  </script>
```

```html
<ul class="table">
  <li>
   <div><b>SYMBOL</b></div>
   <div><b>BID</b></div>
   <div><b>ASK</b></div>
   <div><b>SPREAD</b></div>
  </li>
  <li class="eurusd">
   <div class="symbol">EURUSD</div>
   <div class="bid up">1.17016</div>
   <div class="ask up">1.17017</div>
   <div class="pips">0.1</div>
  </li>
  <li class="gbpusd">
   <div class="symbol">GBPUSD</div>
   <div class="bid up">1.17016</div>
   <div class="ask up">1.17020</div>
   <div class="pips">0.4</div>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

the data in element with Bid and Ask class changes multiple time in second.

I want to use angular to watch these elements value and and add Up or Down class to it if the value is higher than previous value or lower than previous value.

how to do this? an small sample can help me a lot.

Comment: This will depend on how that feed is coming into your application, which you haven't shown here.  In general in Angular (or other SPA frameworks) you don't want to be reading data from the DOM; instead you watch the scope data that's being used to generate the DOM.

Comment: You didn't provide enough code to specify your issue : for all I can see, you're not even using Angular. But I do agree with @DanielBeck that if you use Angular, you should use it the right way, which is the opposite of what you're asking.

Comment: ok I just edited my initial description I don't use Angular yet in my code but I want to use angular to watch the changes or any other way you suggest to achieve my goal